# Layout inflater with DialogFragment

Tags: view, kotlin, layout-inflater

I'm trying to inflate my custom layout (a dialog fragment).

I have this in my function showDialog()

```
    val inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alerts_dialog_remi, null)

    mydialog = Dialog(this, R.style.DialogCustomTheme)
    mydialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.alerts_dialog_remi)
    mydialog.setOnShowListener {
        val text = inflatedView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.alerte_title)
        val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        text.setText("Text")}

        mydialog.create()

        txt = mydialog.findViewById(R.id.close_modal_alerte)
        txt.isEnabled = true
        txt.setOnClickListener{
            mydialog.cancel()
        }
        mydialog.show()
    }
```

But I don't see the "Text" string in my dialog fragment. I tried the put the inflatedView inside setOnShowListener, but it doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to inflate your view, because `dialog.setContentView` does just that for you.

What you need is to get the inflated view from inside your lambda.

Like this:

```
 mydialog.setOnShowListener {
    val text = it.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.alerte_title)
```

Comment: In this example, where does view come from ?

Comment: Works if I replace **it.view** by **mydialog**. Thanks